# react-native start trava em Loading dependency graph

Tags: node.js, react-native, genymotion

Quando eu tento dar um react-native start para testar meu app, ele trava em Loading dependency graph... e nunca vai para o "done.". O pior é que ele começa a consumir toda minha memória até o windows crashar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo problema. Mas depois de uns 10 a 15 minutos ia pra done. Só que até aparecer done, ele consumia toda memória.

Aparentemente o problema esta na versão do react-native, estava usando a versão 0.60.0 mudei para a 0.59.9 e funcionou tranquilo.

Só lembrando que se vc estiver com app aberto no celular ou emulador, tem que fechar e abrir novamente, depois que der done, vai novamente no app e da um reload.

Comment: como você mudou a versão do react native

Comment: na hora de criar o projeto... criei usando o comando react-native init --version 0.59.9 nomeprojeto